# Github DETACHED HEAD error when working with another developer

Tags: github

A developer and I were working on using `.gitignore` to add some conditions to the C# projects and solutions we were committing, since he previously encountered an issue of being unable to commit as a result of us committing binaries (such as `.suo`) to Github as well, which caused conflicts.

We fixed that issue of the `.gitignore`, now it ignores a number of conditions. However, when I went back to my computer, I am currently getting the `DETACHED HEAD` error. I did a `git status`, and the command line has been giving me these messages.

I am unsure how to solve this issue. I was wondering what I can/should do so I can go back to Master and commit/sync my changes?

Also, how do I prevent this issue in the future?

http://puu.sh/6EY9d/ae25db08b9.png

Comment: it says `rebase in progress`. Apparently you were rebasing before and forgot about it. Run `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: Oh interesting! I am back to Master now. And it seems I have no other errors when I do `git status` http://puu.sh/6EYxN/36578ee9c9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I was in rebase, so I ran `git rebase --abort` to get out of that.
2. Afterwards I was back in `master`, which allowed me to commit again.